# NuKeeper unable to find executable git

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am trying to use NuKeeper which updates packages in projects through the azure pipeline.
however i keep getting:

`##[error]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'git'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.`

i'm not sure where the error is occuring.
I've tested the pipeline without NuKeepr and it's fine.

i've followed the steps here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/automate-nuget-package-upgrade-in-azure-pipelines/

My agents were configured like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjCOc4g-AdY

[image]

Comment: Are you using a self-hosted agent or a private agent?

Comment: azure dev ops is on our private server and i added the agents and configured through powershell. So self hosted.

Comment: The error message is very clear about what the issue is. Please explain what you've attempted to do to troubleshoot. i.e. Did you ensure that Git is installed on your private agent and added to the `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> @@@@@@ cd C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\Agent#1
@@@@@@  PS C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\Agent#1> git --version
@@@@@@  git version 2.14.4.windows.2  @@@@@@

after running the git command i get git version back

Answer (score 0):

ok so once adding the path to the folder of the git.exe in the system PATH environment variable.

you also have to restart the machine otherwise despite it recognising the path in cmd it's still not found in Azure dev ops pipeline

---

edit: turns out nukeeper package has bugs when using azure devops which is self hosted (url does not contain azure in its name)

i've instead used dotnet outdated tool to update packages
[image]